# Why read/write split can improve the performance of the database?

Tags: database, database-performance

As far as I know, read/write split will use the master machine to execute CUD operation and use slave machine to do the R operation. And it will resync the data from master to slave. 
So, here is my question: why resync operation is more efficient than doing CUD operation on the slave machine directly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify "more efficient"? Some source of your "As far as I know" would be also useful for better understanding of your question. Thanks!

Comment: @dcieslak sorry for my poor English. Actually, I want to know two things, first is how read/write split synchronize the data between the master server and slave server. The second is, the synchronization is like some "write" option which  is same as the create, update, insert, delete operations that will change the DB on the slave server,. So why read/write split will give a better performance than doing all operation in one server?

Comment: What is your database? Do you think about master-slave replication in sync or async mode? Async mode in replication is most likely faster as your database resources are bigger and you don't need to wait on master for slave replication result. But you can pay by incosistent reads from your slave...